# 'undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard' in libopenh264.so when building FFmpeg with emcc

Tags: ffmpeg, emscripten, webassembly, stack-smash, openh264

I am trying to build [codecbox.js](https://github.com/duanyao/codecbox.js) on Ubuntu 18.04, which involves building FFmpeg with emcc.

At some stage of the build process, FFmpeg's `configure` script tries to process the following code:

```
#include <wels/codec_api.h>
#include <stdint.h>
long check_WelsGetCodecVersion(void) { return (long) WelsGetCodecVersion; }
int main(void) {
    int ret = 0;
    ret |= ((intptr_t)check_WelsGetCodecVersion) & 0xFFFF;
    return ret;
}
```

and I get a linker error:

```
wasm-ld: error: /.../codecbox.js/build/dist/lib/libopenh264.so: undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
```

It seems to be related to [Stack Smashing Protector](https://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Smashing_Protector) compiler feature. I tried to inspect my `libopenh264.so` file with `nm` but `nm` tells me `File format not recognized`. However, using `grep`, I found out that there was a `__stack_chk_guard` symbol in this file.

I tried to rebuild libopenh264 by adding `-fno-stack-protector` and `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to the `CFLAGS` and the `LDFLAGS` but that did not change anything:

```
grep __stack_chk_guard libopenh264.so
```

still answers

```
Binary file libopenh264.so matches
```

I then tried to build the piece of code shown above by adding the same options `-fno-stack-protector` and `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to emcc, but it did not change anything either.

Any idea how to get rid off the problem?

Comment: What's the version of Emacripten?

Comment: Latest, 1.39.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not rebuilt libopenh264 completely.

Adding `-fno-stack-protector` and `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to the `CFLAGS`, the `CXXFLAGS` and the `LDFLAGS` then doing `make clean` and `make` solved the problem: libopenh264.so no longer embedded symbol `__stack_chk_guard`.

Comment: Sometime make clean do the magic thing!